# What do you call a power plant that generates both electricity and heat?

Tags: single-word-requests

There are thermal power stations that generate both electricity and heat which is used for heating residential houses close to it.

There are quite a few such power plants in, among others, [Russia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8), [Ukraine](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B) (both links in Russian), and (to a lesser extent) Germany:

- In Russian, Ukrainian, and Belorussian, it is called  [теплоэлектроцентраль](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C), literally "heat and electricity central".
- The German word is [Heizkraftwerk](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heizkraftwerk), literally "heating power plant" (a power plant that heats).

What do you call such power plant in English?

**Sample sentence**

> Contrary to a thermal power plant, a `<BLANK>` generates not only electricity, but also provides heating for houses in its vicinity.

`<BLANK>` is the word I am looking for.

**What I could find on my own**

In a Wikipedia article on [district heating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/District_heating#Russia) I found the term **combined heat and power plant**. What I find a little confusing is that it links to an article about [cogeneration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cogeneration#Cogeneration_in_Europe) which, at a first glance, looks like some modern, fancy innovation. This is definitely not true for such power plants in the ex-USSR because they have been there for decades.

According to [Google NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=combined+heat+and+power+plant%2Ccogeneration%2Cdistrict+heating%2C+thermal+power+plant&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccombined%20heat%20and%20power%20plant%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccogeneration%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdistrict%20heating%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthermal%20power%20plant%3B%2Cc0) this term is used relatively rarely:

[image: Word frequency diagram from Google NGram]

Comment: What is considered an innovation depends more on the scope of the innovation’s context: recovering “waste” heat is unusual in some places’ power industry, so getting it to be accepted is an innovation on a more local scale, especially if it was not learned from a foreign power industry where it is already common.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process is called [cogeneration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cogeneration).

The plants are called **CHP** (Combined heat and power ) plants.

From Wikipedia:

> **Combined heat and power (CHP) plants** recover otherwise wasted thermal energy for heating. This is also called combined heat and power district heating. Small CHP plants are an example of decentralized energy. ... The resulting low-temperature waste heat is then used for water or space heating.

Comment: I filled out a rather complex form at FERC (see https://www.ferc.gov/docs-filing/ferconline.asp). They name this cogeneration.